# Display single Column from sqlite to listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a database of universities. I just want to display the university name column in the listview. For that, I have created getData() object which will fetch the row. Then it would be displayed in the listview. I'm getting the university name from the database but the format is not correct. I'm just getting random multiple university names in list view.

Here is my database file

```
public class UniversityFinderDB  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 1;
static final String DATABASE_NAME="universities.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="universityFinder";

private static final String COLUMN_UNIVID="univId";
private static final String COLUMN_UNIVERSITYNAME="univName";
private static final String COLUMN_SCORE="score";

SQLiteDatabase db;




private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table IF NOT EXISTS universityFinder (univId integer PRIMARY KEY , univName varchar not null, score integer not null);";

public UniversityFinderDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null ,DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);


}


public void addUser(Universities universities) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_UNIVID, universities.getUnivId());
    values.put(COLUMN_UNIVERSITYNAME, universities.getUnivName());
    values.put(COLUMN_SCORE, universities.getGre());



    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}



public List<String> getData(int input){
    String query="select univName from universityFinder  where score >="+input+"";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(query, null);

    List<String> attrStr = new Vector<String>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            attrStr.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_UNIVERSITYNAME)));
            Arrays.toString(new List[]{attrStr});
        }while  (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){

    }
    return attrStr;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(db);
}


}
```

here is the listview file where it will get the score from the user and then will only display the universities with that score or higher. But instead of that, I'm just getting a random list of universities in output.

```
public class ListviewFinderUniversities extends AppCompatActivity {

UniversityFinderDB myDB;
Universities universities;

ListView finderListview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview_finder_universities);


     myDB = new UniversityFinderDB(this);
     universities = new Universities();

    int gre = getIntent().getIntExtra("Gre",0);


    finderListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.finderListView);


    List<String> data = myDB.getData(gre);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListviewFinderUniversities.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

    finderListview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Couple of code review comments/tips: It is probably best to use a 'CursorAdapter' instead of an 'ArrayAdapter' and a 'CursorLoader' or 'ASyncTask'  instead of querying on the main thread. Also, 'close()' is not being called on the cursor, that should happen inside the 'finally' clause of a 'try'. Using 'while (cursor.moveToNext())' is probably better than using 'if' and 'do-while'. It is difficult to comment on the output without knowing the contents of the DB, but it might be beneficial to write a little routine to log the full contents of the DB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below query:
To avoid multiple names and also to get the list in an order

String query="select distinct univName from universityFinder  where score >= " +input+ " order by univName ";